# how to display many polygons with shared vertices in cesium

Tags: cesiumjs

I would like to display 100,000 or more polygons in Cesium.  The polygons have a lot of shared boundaries --- they are essentially like US zip code polygons but smaller, so there are more of them --- so I'd like to use a representation that takes advantage of this and is "aware" of the topology of shared boundaries and only stores each vertex once.

I'm fairly new to programming with Cesium (but familiar with 3D graphics in general); I've scanned the tutorials and docs and don't immediately see a way to create a polygon collection with shared vertices.  I have my polygons in a topojson file and tried loading it using code like what is in the topojson example:

```
var promise = Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.load('./polygons.topojson');
promise.then(function(dataSource) {
    viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource);
    ...
});
```

But

- this doesn't take advantage of the shared vertices because the GeoJsonDataSource converts each individual polygon to a GeoJson object, and
- it crashes my browser, presumably because 100,000 separate GeoJson objects is more than it can handle.

I feel fairly sure (and hopeful) that there is a way to do this in Cesium, but I haven't found it yet.  Can someone tell me what the most effective approach would be, in particular what primitives / loader utilities should I be looking at?

Ultimately, by the way, the application I want to write will never actually render all 100,000 polygons at the same time --- it will choose which ones to render based on the mouse position, and at any one time it will only render a few thousand of them.  But I want to load them all into memory ahead of time, so that I can change which ones are being rendered in real time as the cursor moves around.